# Action after specific Button Clicks

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just want to know how to start an Action (like starting a new Activity) after for example 3 Button clicks. So the Activity will only start if the Button has been clicked for 3 Times.

Comment: What sort of code/approaches have you researched, tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter of the times you've clicked the `Button` anywhere you like, such as a global variable or if you want it to be cleaner, the `Button` itself. Add a listener to your button, you can simply add `android:onClick="buttonClick"` to the xml and then implement a method with that name like so:

```
public void buttonClick(View yourButton){
    if(yourButton.getTag() == null){ //We have no tags, so first click :)
        yourButton.setTag(1);
    }

    if((Integer)yourButton.getTag() == 3){
        //Do whatever
    }else{
        //Increment the value of the tag
        yourButton.setTag(((Integer)yourButton.getTag())+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!Exactly what  I wanted!

Comment: And how can I save the Button clicks in the Shared Preference? So the App remembers the Button Clicks even when the app is closed.

Comment: give each button an id, say "button1" or whatever, then store that in shared preferences inside the part where you update the tag. Remember to *set* the tag value on relaunch too

Comment: Ok. I gave my Button the ID "button1". Then I searched for a long time to know how to save that Button Clicks to a file in the Shared Preference, but with no luck,so it would be AWESOME if you could show me how the Code to store the Button Clicks to a file in the Shared Preference looks like!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a counter .. Increment it after every click... Check if value equals desired value then build intent and start the activity .. Reset the counter before starting the activity.